# Having trouble with installing drivers for TL-WN722N

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, compiling

I have some major issues when I try to install my new TL-WN722N V3. I've tried with a bunch of different rlt8188eu drivers wich TP-Link suggest. Whenever I try to compile the drivers it always fails.

```
jones@pilotz-MunchCave:~/Desktop/rtl8188eus$ make all
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-28-generic/build M=/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28-generic'
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
  CC [M]  /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.o
In file included from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:35:0,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:24:
/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/wifi.h:988:0: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40

In file included from ./include/net/cfg80211.h:21:0,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service_linux.h:83,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:45,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:24:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1441:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100

/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘isFileReadable’:
/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1833:28: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_ds’; did you mean ‘get_da’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   oldfs = get_fs(); set_fs(get_ds());
                            ^~~~~~
                            get_da
/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1833:28: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
In file included from ./include/linux/uaccess.h:11:0,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:37,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:24:
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:20: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t {aka struct <anonymous>}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
                    ^~~~~~
/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘retriveFromFile’:
/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1861:29: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
    oldfs = get_fs(); set_fs(get_ds());
                             ^~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/uaccess.h:11:0,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:37,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:24:
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:20: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t {aka struct <anonymous>}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
                    ^~~~~~
/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘storeToFile’:
/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:1895:29: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
    oldfs = get_fs(); set_fs(get_ds());
                             ^~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/uaccess.h:11:0,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/osdep_service.h:37,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.c:24:
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:20: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t {aka struct <anonymous>}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
                    ^~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:288: recipe for target '/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Error 1
Makefile:1655: recipe for target '_module_/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/jones/Desktop/rtl8188eus] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28-generic'
Makefile:1367: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

lsusb output

```
jones@pilotz-MunchCave:~/Desktop/rtl8188eus$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b62a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:010c  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Please help me.

Comment: Drivers from Tp-Link site are old and won't build on modern Ubuntu. Look for `rtl8188eus` solutions at this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install RTL8188EUS driver on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170202/how-to-install-rtl8188eus-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I've looked everywhere on forums on youtube. Doesn't matter what I do, I can never compile without error.