# Wi-Fi Very unstable (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Realtek USB Adapter)

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, realtek-wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with XFCE and the wifi works fine but some times it keeps disconnecting. (Windows WiFi works fine).
I tried changing the DNS, some IPV6 settings and some other stuff but nothing worked.
Is there any setting or something on the wifi? Thanks.

lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a2c:2d23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 275d:0ba6  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Most likely its the driver. DNS can not cause a disconnect.

Comment: Please include the output of `lsusb` in your question.

Comment: @mchid Ok, I already did.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install RTL8188EUS driver on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1170249/167115). Please let us know if the DKMS commands don't work or if you try another solution. Long story short, you need to install the rtl8188eu driver.

Comment: @mchid When I try to do "sudo dkms build 8188eu/1.0" it gives me the error: "Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/8188eu-1.0 does not exist."

Comment: @TheNiceGuy Okay. First, delete what you have done `sudo rm -r ~/DriverBuild` Then, install the headers `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic` and then run the exact commands listed in the answer one by one over again after `# Go install the driver `.

Comment: @TheNiceGuy Also, copy and paste the commands into the terminal instead of typing them in so there are no mistakes.

Comment: @mchid Same error, that did not worked.

Comment: @TheNiceGuy I don't know what to tell you. I followed the instructions and didn't get an error. If you would like, you can open a separate question for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If WIFI works fine otherwise, you can bypass DHCP and set a static IP (local IP) on both your Ubuntu settings and your wireless router settings for the Ubuntu machine. Use the existing local IP as the static IP.

Go to **system settings > Networks > wireless** and take note of the **IPV4 address** and the **Default Route**.

Then, click on the **Settings** for that network, click on the **IPV4 settings** tab and click in the field for **Address**.

Type in the local IPV4 address (example: 192.168.1.10) and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Type in the **Netmask** 255.255.255.0 and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Type in the **Gateway** (default route) (example: 192.168.1.1)

and then click **Save**.

You *must* do this in that particular order and if you mess up it won't let you click save and you will have to re-enter the data all over again.

Finally, go into your router settings and set the same static IPV4 address for your Ubuntu machine in your router settings.

Also, don't forget to restart network manager when you are done to apply the changes:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```